# How to vertically align `<ol>` number to the top?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align my `<ol>` numbers vertically to the top. Here's a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/mattmcgilton/pen/YzwaGEW).

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;
  font-size: 11px;
}

a {
  font-size: 80px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#">Header One</a><span>This is some text, don't move me</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Header Two</a><span>This is some text, don't move me</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Header Three</a><span>This is some text, don't move me</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Header Four</a><span>This is some text, don't move me</span></li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Comment: but in snippet I see your code is running well

Comment: In the future the `::marker` pseudo-element will let you solve this problem very easily, but [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker#Browser_compatibility) is currently quite patchy

Comment: The number is currently at the bottom, I want it to be at the top

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible. I do know you probably *shouldn't*. Bottom alignment is standard and expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a custom counter by setting the `counter-reset` and `counter-increment` CSS properties and displaying with the before pseudo element of each `li` element. `vertical-align: top` and adjusting the `line-height` can be used to align the counter to the top of the text.

Demo:

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: items;
  font-size: 11px;
}

ol li {
  counter-increment: items;
}

ol li:before {
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 45px;
}

ol li:before {
  content: "0" counter(items) ". ";
}

ol li:nth-child(n+10):before {
  content: counter(items) ". ";
}

a {
  font-size: 80px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#">Header One</a><span>This is some text, don't move me</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Header Two</a><span>This is some text, don't move me</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Header Three</a><span>This is some text, don't move me</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Header Four</a><span>This is some text, don't move me</span></li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Comment: A good solution, but I think it can be done more simply, without the counters. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the trouble is the tall anchor element, you can apply `vertical-align:top` to the **anchor** tag. That should do the trick. You may need to adjust `line-height` on the `<a>` tag and set both `line-height` and `margin` on the `<li>` to make it look right. You’ll probably also want to put `vertical-align:bottom` on the `<span>`, if I get your intention right. But, based on your CodePen, I think this will get you the effect you’re looking for.
Here’s my [CodePen fork](https://codepen.io/goldnate/pen/JjGLbWE).

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 300px;
}

li {
  margin: .6em 0;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

a {
  font-size: 80px;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: .8;
}

span {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#">Header One</a><span>This is some text, don't move me. Also, let's see how this looks if the line is long and there is more than one. And what if there's more text outside the span tag? </span> And what if there's more text outside the
      span tag? In that case, just make sure that the span and the li tag have the same line height.</li>
    <li><a href="#">Header Two</a><span>This is some text, don't move me</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Header Three</a><span>This is some text, don't move me</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Header Four</a><span>This is some text, don't move me</span></li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Floated blocks are essentially treated as having no height as far as the line numbers are concerned, so if you wrap up the content of the `<li>` in a `<div>` and then float that to the left, then the line numbers will be positioned above the div.

Then, we just need to use part a clearfix to make the floated div actually take up space and ensure the items below do appear below, rather than to the right of the previous item.

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;
  font-size: 11px;
}

a {
  font-size: 80px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.listContent {
  float: left;
}

/** Clearfix **/
li {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ol>    
    <li><div class="listContent"><a href="#">Header Two</a><span>This is some text, don't move me</span></div></li>
    <li><div class="listContent"><a href="#">Header Three</a><span>This is some text, don't move me</span></div></li>
    <li><div class="listContent"><a href="#">Header Four</a><span>This is some text, don't move me</span></div></li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

---

In the future, you'll be able to use the `::marker` pseudo-element to apply specific styles to just the marker (e.g. the numbering or bullet points of a list). From what I understand, something as simple as

```
li::marker {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

could get this done.

However, this is still in the early stages of gaining browser support at the time of writing -- you can see the support matrix [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

Since the `::marker` is anchored to the element inside the `li`, in order to align the `::marker`, you need to align the element inside the `li`.

```css
li {
    width: 350px;
}

div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
            aliqua... 
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```